# Elasticsearch query to return all records

Tags: database, elasticsearch, query-string, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a small database in Elasticsearch and for testing purposes would like to pull all records back.  I am attempting to use a URL of the form...

```
http://localhost:9200/foo/_search?pretty=true&q={'matchAll':{''}}
```

Can someone give me the URL you would use to accomplish this, please?

Comment: ...where "foo" is the name of the index you want to show all records for.

Comment: All the answers using only `size` query parameter are not correct. Irrespective of value of `size` in query, ES will return at max `index.max_result_window` docs (which default to 10k) in response. Refer `scroll` and `search_after`.

Comment: I was able to return all records with only this line: `http://curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/foo/_search'`

Answer (score 910, accepted):

I think lucene syntax is supported so:

`http://localhost:9200/foo/_search?pretty=true&q=*:*`

size defaults to 10, so you may also need `&size=BIGNUMBER` to get more than 10 items. (where BIGNUMBER equals a number you believe is bigger than your dataset)

BUT, elasticsearch documentation [suggests](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-type.html) for large result sets, using the scan search type.

EG:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/foo/_search?search_type=scan&scroll=10m&size=50' -d '
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
    }
}'
```

and then keep requesting as per the documentation link above suggests.

EDIT: `scan` Deprecated in 2.1.0.

`scan` does not provide any benefits over a regular `scroll` request sorted by `_doc`. [link to elastic docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-type.html#scan) (spotted by @christophe-roussy)

Comment: Thanks. This was the final I came up with that returns what I need for now...http://localhost:9200/foo/_search?size=50&pretty=true&q=*:*

Comment: Adding to @Steve's answer, you can find a list of parameters that elasticsearch understands in this link http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/uri-request/

Comment: Is it possible to run a scan search with a query other than a match_all query?

Comment: @Churro u should post a question, not hide it in the comments. but short answer, yes. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/query/

Comment: Thanks @Steve for your answer. I didn't think it was significant enough for a new question. It wasn't explicitly stated anywhere, so I figured I'd ask here just to verify.

Comment: You should really use the scan+scroll-requests. If you do use size=BIGNUMBER, note that Lucene allocates memory for scores for that number, so don't make it exceedingly large. :)

Comment: Did you really mean to use `-d` with `-XGET`?

Comment: I was unaware of the `?size=<N>` query string parameter until your answer, @SteveCasey. Thank you **so** much for posting this. My use case just requires me to list _all_ the documents in a small index (generally <200 items), so appending `?size=1000` to the query made it fire right up.

Comment: hey @SteveCasey I am struggling to find this answer. Could you please help me - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34481152/sort-by-geo-distance-where-latitude-and-longitude-given-is-0-00-in-elasticsearch?noredirect=1#comment56708837_34481152

Comment: Scan was deprecated in deprecated in 2.1.0: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-type.html#scan

Comment: @SteveCasey Ideally ES should respond with something special: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884141/convention-for-http-response-header-to-notify-clients-of-deprecated-api, another interesting problem ...

Comment: Seeing as scan is deprecated, should this answer be updated to use scroll?

Comment: Yes. Well a scan is a type of scroll. The answer should not include the 'search_type=scan' parameter. You don't need it, and it is deprecated.

Comment: Actually I've just noticed "search_type:scan" is not only deprecated. It was removed in elasticsearch version 5.0: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/breaking_50_search_changes.html#_literal_search_type_scan_literal_removed

Comment: as scan was deprecated, i just changed it to search_type=query_then_fetch . That helped me a lot , thanks!

Answer (score 184):

```
http://127.0.0.1:9200/foo/_search/?size=1000&pretty=1
                                   ^
```

**Note the size param**, which increases the hits displayed from the default (10) to 1000 per shard.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html

Comment: One thing to keep in mind though (from Elasticsearch docs): Note that from + size can not be more than the index.max_result_window index setting which defaults to 10,000.

Comment: This will return 1000, not all, user3078523 is right, this method has a limit of `max_result_window`

Comment: It has a maximum, and also (if you have many thousands of records to get) it's a rather noddy heavy approach to be going up towards that maximum. Instead you should use a "scroll" query.

Comment: you should pass `pretty` param as boolean: `curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/logs/_search/?size=1000&pretty=true'`

Comment: this is the answer I'm looking for. the one without passing the request parameter `q`. thank you!

Answer (score 48):

elasticsearch(ES) supports both a GET or a POST request for getting the data from the ES cluster index.

When we do a GET:

```
http://localhost:9200/[your index name]/_search?size=[no of records you want]&q=*:*
```

When we do a POST:

```
http://localhost:9200/[your_index_name]/_search
{
  "size": [your value] //default 10
  "from": [your start index] //default 0
  "query":
   {
    "match_all": {}
   }
}
```

I would suggest to use a UI plugin with elasticsearch http://mobz.github.io/elasticsearch-head/
This will help you get a better feeling of the indices you create and also test your indices.

Comment: As another user mentioned:  `from` + `size` can not be more than the `index.max_result_window` index setting which defaults to 10,000

Comment: This approach has a maximum, and also (if you have many thousands of records to get) it's a rather noddy heavy approach to be going up towards that maximum. Instead you should use a "scroll" query

Comment: Oddly enough, the official docs show `curl -XGET ... -d '{...}'` which is an `un`official mixed style of request.  Thank you for showing the correct GET and POST formats.

Answer (score 35):

> **Note:** The answer relates to an older version of Elasticsearch `0.90`. Versions released since then have an updated syntax. Please refer to other answers that may provide a more accurate answer to the latest answer that you are looking for.

The query below would return the NO_OF_RESULTS you would like to be returned..

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/foo/_search?size=NO_OF_RESULTS' -d '
{
"query" : {
    "match_all" : {}
  }
}'
```

Now, the question here is that you want **all** the records to be returned. So naturally, before writing a query, you wont know the value of **NO_OF_RESULTS**.

How do we know how many records exist in your document? Simply type the query below

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/foo/_search' -d '
```

This would give you a result that looks like the one below

```
 {
hits" : {
  "total" :       2357,
  "hits" : [
    {
      ..................
```

The result **total** tells you how many records are available in your document. So, that's a nice way to know the value of **NO_OF RESULTS**

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_search' -d '
```

Search all types in all indices

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/foo/_search' -d '
```

Search all types in the foo index

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/foo1,foo2/_search' -d '
```

Search all types in the foo1 and foo2 indices

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/f*/_search
```

Search all types in any indices beginning with f

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_all/type1,type2/_search' -d '
```

Search types user and tweet in all indices

Comment: By default ES will return 10 results unless a size param is included in the base query.

Comment: The previous response was three years old. Updated it to a current one.

Answer (score 27):

This is the best solution I found using python client

```py
  # Initialize the scroll
  page = es.search(
  index = 'yourIndex',
  doc_type = 'yourType',
  scroll = '2m',
  search_type = 'scan',
  size = 1000,
  body = {
    # Your query's body
    })
  sid = page['_scroll_id']
  scroll_size = page['hits']['total']

  # Start scrolling
  while (scroll_size > 0):
    print "Scrolling..."
    page = es.scroll(scroll_id = sid, scroll = '2m')
    # Update the scroll ID
    sid = page['_scroll_id']
    # Get the number of results that we returned in the last scroll
    scroll_size = len(page['hits']['hits'])
    print "scroll size: " + str(scroll_size)
    # Do something with the obtained page
```

https://gist.github.com/drorata/146ce50807d16fd4a6aa

Using java client

```java
import static org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders.*;

QueryBuilder qb = termQuery("multi", "test");

SearchResponse scrollResp = client.prepareSearch(test)
        .addSort(FieldSortBuilder.DOC_FIELD_NAME, SortOrder.ASC)
        .setScroll(new TimeValue(60000))
        .setQuery(qb)
        .setSize(100).execute().actionGet(); //100 hits per shard will be returned for each scroll
//Scroll until no hits are returned
do {
    for (SearchHit hit : scrollResp.getHits().getHits()) {
        //Handle the hit...
    }

    scrollResp = client.prepareSearchScroll(scrollResp.getScrollId()).setScroll(new TimeValue(60000)).execute().actionGet();
} while(scrollResp.getHits().getHits().length != 0); // Zero hits mark the end of the scroll and the while loop.
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-search-scrolling.html

Comment: Thanks Mark, that was exactly what I was looking for!
In my case (ELK 6.2.1, python 3), the search_type argument was not valid and the document_type isn't needed any more since ELK 6.0

Comment: Perfect solution! Thanks. I was using `elasticsearch_dsl==5.4.0` and it works without `search_type = 'scan',`.

Comment: ES 6.3. This example makes my Elasticsearch service to crash, trying to scroll 110k documents with `size=10000`, at somewhere between 5th-7th iterations.
with `status=127`, `main ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in Appenders`, `main ERROR Unable to locate appender "rolling" for logger config "root"`
No logs in `/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log`

Comment: For the record, the python clients implements a `scan` helpers` that does the scroll under the hood (since version 5.x.x at leat)

Comment: `search_type = 'scan'` is deprecated. Similar code will work without that, although there are some interesting differences which are well buried in the old documentation. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-request-scroll.html#scroll-scan   In particular, when migrating to not use search_type=scan, that first 'search' query will come with the first batch of results to process.

Answer (score 23):

**If it's a small dataset (e.g. 1K records)**, you can simply specify `size`:

```
curl localhost:9200/foo_index/_search?size=1000
```

The [match all query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-all-query.html) isn't needed, as it's implicit.

**If you have a medium-sized dataset, like 1M records**, you may not have enough memory to load it, so you need a [scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-scroll).

A scroll is like a cursor in a DB. In Elasticsearch, it remembers where you left off and keeps the same view of the index (i.e. prevents the searcher from going away with a [refresh](https://sematext.com/blog/elasticsearch-refresh-interval-vs-indexing-performance/), prevents [segments from merging](https://sematext.com/blog/solr-optimize-is-not-bad-for-you-lucene-solr-revolution/)).

API-wise, you have to add a scroll parameter to the first request:

```
curl 'localhost:9200/foo_index/_search?size=100&scroll=1m&pretty'
```

You get back the first page and a scroll ID:

```
{
  "_scroll_id" : "DXF1ZXJ5QW5kRmV0Y2gBAAAAAAAAADEWbmJlSmxjb2hSU0tMZk12aEx2c0EzUQ==",
  "took" : 0,
...
```

Remember that **both the scroll ID you get back and the timeout are valid for the next page**. A common mistake here is to specify a very large timeout (value of `scroll`), that would cover for processing the whole dataset (e.g. 1M records) instead of one page (e.g. 100 records).

To get the next page, fill in the last scroll ID and a timeout that should last until fetching the following page:

```
curl -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'localhost:9200/_search/scroll' -d '{
  "scroll": "1m",
  "scroll_id": "DXF1ZXJ5QW5kRmV0Y2gBAAAAAAAAADAWbmJlSmxjb2hSU0tMZk12aEx2c0EzUQ=="
}'
```

**If you have a lot to export (e.g. 1B documents)**, you'll want to parallelise. This can be done via [sliced scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#sliced-scroll). Say you want to export on 10 threads. The first thread would issue a request like this:

```
curl -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'localhost:9200/test/_search?scroll=1m&size=100' -d '{
  "slice": {
    "id": 0, 
    "max": 10 
  }
}'
```

You get back the first page and a scroll ID, exactly like a normal scroll request. You'd consume it exactly like a regular scroll, except that you get 1/10th of the data.

Other threads would do the same, except that `id` would be 1, 2, 3...

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed to understand (size); it helped me troubleshoot my empty (`[ ]`) returns.

Answer (score 20):

If you want to pull many thousands of records then... a few people gave the right answer of using 'scroll' (Note: Some people also suggested using "search_type=scan". This was deprecated, and in v5.0 removed. You don't need it)

Start with a 'search' query, but specifying a 'scroll' parameter (here I'm using a 1 minute timeout):

```
curl -XGET 'http://ip1:9200/myindex/_search?scroll=1m' -d '
{
    "query": {
            "match_all" : {}
    }
}
'
```

That includes your first 'batch' of hits. But we are not done here. The output of the above curl command would be something like this:

```
{"_scroll_id":"c2Nhbjs1OzUyNjE6NU4tU3BrWi1UWkNIWVNBZW43bXV3Zzs1Mzc3OkhUQ0g3VGllU2FhemJVNlM5d2t0alE7NTI2Mjo1Ti1TcGtaLVRaQ0hZU0FlbjdtdXdnOzUzNzg6SFRDSDdUaWVTYWF6YlU2Uzl3a3RqUTs1MjYzOjVOLVNwa1otVFpDSFlTQWVuN211d2c7MTt0b3RhbF9oaXRzOjIyNjAxMzU3Ow==","took":109,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":22601357,"max_score":0.0,"hits":[]}}
```

It's important to have _scroll_id handy as next you should run the following command:

```
    curl -XGET  'localhost:9200/_search/scroll'  -d'
    {
        "scroll" : "1m", 
        "scroll_id" : "c2Nhbjs2OzM0NDg1ODpzRlBLc0FXNlNyNm5JWUc1" 
    }
    '
```

However, passing the scroll_id around is not something designed to be done manually. Your best bet is to write code to do it. e.g. in java:

```java
    private TransportClient client = null;
    private Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
                  .put(CLUSTER_NAME,"cluster-test").build();
    private SearchResponse scrollResp  = null;

    this.client = new TransportClient(settings);
    this.client.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("ip", port));

    QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery();
    scrollResp = client.prepareSearch(index).setSearchType(SearchType.SCAN)
                 .setScroll(new TimeValue(60000))                            
                 .setQuery(queryBuilder)
                 .setSize(100).execute().actionGet();

    scrollResp = client.prepareSearchScroll(scrollResp.getScrollId())
                .setScroll(new TimeValue(timeVal))
                .execute()
                .actionGet();
```

Now LOOP on the last command use SearchResponse to extract the data.

Answer (score 18):

Elasticsearch will get **significant** slower if you just add some big number as size, one method to use to get all documents is using scan and scroll ids.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html

In Elasticsearch v7.2, you do it like this:

```
POST /foo/_search?scroll=1m
{
    "size": 100,
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}
```

The results from this would contain a _scroll_id which you have to query to get the next 100 chunk.

```
POST /_search/scroll 
{
    "scroll" : "1m", 
    "scroll_id" : "<YOUR SCROLL ID>" 
}
```

Comment: This answer needs more updates. `search_type=scan` is now deprecated. So you should remove that, but then the behaviour has changed a little. The first batch of data comes back from the initial search call. The link you provide does show the correct way to do it.

Comment: My comment was really to note that you can't just add any number as size, as it would be quite a lot slower. So I removed the code example and people can follow the link to get correct code.

Comment: @WoodyDRN It is better to have the code in your answer (even if it gets old) so it is still available when the link dies.

Answer (score 12):

use `server:9200/_stats` also to get statistics about all your aliases.. like size and number of elements per alias, that's very useful and provides helpful information

Comment: But, from what I remember, ES only allow getting 16000 data per request. So if the data is above 16000, this solution is not enough.

Answer (score 10):

You actually don't need to pass a body to `match_all`, it can be done with a GET request to the following URL. This is the simplest form.

`http://localhost:9200/foo/_search`

Answer (score 6):

The best way to adjust the size is using size=**number** in front of the URL

```
Curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/logstash-*/_search?size=50&pretty"
```

Note: maximum value which can be defined in this size is 10000. For any value above ten thousand it expects you to use scroll function which would minimise any chances of impacts to performance.

Comment: Since which version does max size occur?

Comment: That may be the "best" way up to a point, but a bit noddy really. If you have many thousands of records, then the best way is a "scroll" query.

Comment: With the from and size-approach you will run into the Deep Pagination problem. Use the scroll API to make a dump of all documents.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`_count`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html) API to get the value for the `size` parameter:

```
http://localhost:9200/foo/_count?q=<your query>
```

Returns `{count:X, ...}`. Extract value 'X' and then do the actual query:

```
http://localhost:9200/foo/_search?q=<your query>&size=X
```

Comment: Setting the size to X like this, might have a surprising concurrency glitch: Consider what happens if a record is added in between doing the count and setting the size on your next query...   but also if you have many thousands of records to get, then it's the wrong approach. Instead you should use a "scroll" query.

Answer (score 5):

Simple! You can use `size` and `from` parameter!

```
http://localhost:9200/[your index name]/_search?size=1000&from=0
```

then you change the `from` gradually until you get all of the data.

Comment: never use this method if the data contains many documents... Each time you go to "the next page" Elastic will be slower and slower! Use SearchAfter instead

Comment: Also, this solution will not work if the overall data size is above 10 000.  The option size=1000&from=10001 would fail.

Comment: Indeed fails. Parameters `from` + `size` can't be more than index.max_result_window index setting which defaults to 10,000

Comment: If the data contains many thousands of documents, the correct answer is to use a 'scroll' query.

Comment: With the `from` and `size`-approach you will run into the Deep Pagination problem. Use the scroll API to make a dump of all documents.

Answer (score 5):

From Kibana DevTools its:

```
GET my_index_name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

http://localhost:9200/foo/_search/?**size**=1000&pretty=1

you will need to specify size query parameter as the default is 10

Comment: With the from and size-approach you will run into the Deep Pagination problem. Use the scroll API to make a dump of all documents.

Answer (score 4):

**size** param increases the hits displayed from from the default(10) to 500.

```
http://localhost:9200/[indexName]/_search?pretty=true&size=500&q=*:*
```

Change the **from** step by step to get all the data.

```
http://localhost:9200/[indexName]/_search?size=500&from=0
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution using the python package [elasticsearch-dsl](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py):

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search
from elasticsearch_dsl import connections

connections.create_connection(hosts=['localhost'])

s = Search(index="foo")
response = s.scan()

count = 0
for hit in response:
    # print(hit.to_dict())  # be careful, it will printout every hit in your index
    count += 1

print(count)
```

See also https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#elasticsearch_dsl.Search.scan .

Comment: this was very helpful - changed everything for me now i can actually hope to get results within the night.

Answer (score 4):

Using kibana console and my_index as the index to search the following can be contributed. Asking the index to only return 4 fields of the index, you can also add size to indicate how many documents that you want to be returned by the index. As of ES 7.6 you should use _source rather than filter it will respond faster.

```
GET /address/_search
 {
   "_source": ["streetaddress","city","state","postcode"],
   "size": 100,
   "query":{
   "match_all":{ }
    }   
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

For Elasticsearch 6.x

Request: `GET /foo/_search?pretty=true`

Response: In Hits-> total, give the count of the docs

```
    {
      "took": 1,
      "timed_out": false,
      "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
      },
      "hits": {
        "total": 1001,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
          {
```

Answer (score 2):

```
curl -X GET 'localhost:9200/foo/_search?q=*&pretty'
```

Answer (score 2):

By default Elasticsearch return 10 records so size should be provided explicitly.

Add size with request to get desire number of records.

http://{host}:9200/{index_name}/_search?pretty=true&size=(number of records)

Note : 
  Max page size can not be more than index.max_result_window index setting which defaults to 10,000.

Answer (score 1):

To return all records from all indices you can do:

`curl -XGET http://35.195.120.21:9200/_all/_search?size=50&pretty`

Output:

```
  "took" : 866,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 25,
    "successful" : 25,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 512034694,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "grafana-dash",
      "_type" : "dashboard",
      "_id" : "test",
      "_score" : 1.0,
       ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The maximum result which will return by elasticSearch is 10000 by providing the size

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/index/type/_search?scroll=1m' -d '
{
   "size":10000,
   "query" : {
   "match_all" : {}
    }
}'
```

After that, you have to use Scroll API for getting the result and get the _scroll_id value and put this value in scroll_id

```
curl -XGET  'localhost:9200/_search/scroll'  -d'
{
   "scroll" : "1m", 
   "scroll_id" : "" 
}'
```

Comment: The scroll API should be used right from the start with the very first request.

Answer (score 1):

If still someone is looking for all the data to be retrieved from Elasticsearch like me for some usecases, here is what I did. Moreover, all the data means, all the indexes and all the documents types. I'm using Elasticsearch 6.3

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_search?pretty=true" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}
'
```

[Elasticsearch reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-all-query.html)

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation provides the answer to this question! you can find it [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-query-lang.html).

```
{
  "query": { "match_all": {} },
  "size": 1
}
```

You simply replace size (1) with the number of results you want to see!

Comment: The author of the question was asking for 'all' results, not a pre-defined amount of results. While it is helpful to post a link to the docs, the docs do not describe how to achieve that, neither does your answer.

Comment: With the from and size-approach you will run into the Deep Pagination problem. Use the scroll API to make a dump of all documents.

Answer (score 1):

this is the query to accomplish what you want,
(I am suggesting to use Kibana, as it helps to understand queries better)

```
GET my_index_name/my_type_name/_search
{
   "query":{
      "match_all":{}
   },
   size : 20,
   from : 3
}
```

to get all records you have to use "match_all" query.

size is the no of records you want to fetch (kind of limit).
by default, ES will only return 10 records

from is like skip, skip first 3 records.

If you want to fetch exactly all the records, just use the value from the "total" field 
from the result once you hit this query from Kibana and the use it with "size".

Comment: The limitation of this query is that size + from must be lower or equal to "index.max_result_window". For large number of documents (by default 10000+) this query is not applicable.

Answer (score 0):

None except @Akira Sendoh has answered how to actually get ALL docs. But even that solution crashes my **ES 6.3** service without logs. The only thing that worked for me using the low-level `elasticsearch-py` library was through [scan helper](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html?highlight=scroll) that uses `scroll()` api:

```
from elasticsearch.helpers import scan

doc_generator = scan(
    es_obj,
    query={"query": {"match_all": {}}},
    index="my-index",
)

# use the generator to iterate, dont try to make a list or you will get out of RAM
for doc in doc_generator:
    # use it somehow
```

However, the cleaner way nowadays seems to be through `elasticsearch-dsl` library, that offers more abstract, cleaner calls, e.g: http://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html#hits

Answer (score 0):

Using Elasticsearch 7.5.1

```
http://${HOST}:9200/${INDEX}/_search?pretty=true&q=*:*&scroll=10m&size=5000
```

in case you can also specify the size of your array with &size=${number}

in case you  don't know you index

```
http://${HOST}:9200/_cat/indices?v
```

Answer (score -5):

You can  use size=0 this will return you all the documents 
example

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/index/type/_search' -d '
{
   size:0,
   "query" : {
   "match_all" : {}
    }
}'
```

Comment: This will return an accumulated information, but not the hits themselves