# Convention for HTTP response header to notify clients of deprecated API

Tags: rest, http, http-status-codes, deprecation-warning

I'm upgrading our REST API endpoints and I want to notify clients when they are calling the to-be-deprecated endpoint.
What header should I use in the response with a message along the lines of "This API version is being deprecated, please consult the latest documentation to update your endpoints"

Answer (score 91, accepted):

I would not change anything in the status code to be backward compatible. I would add a "Warning" header in the response :

```
Warning: 299 - "Deprecated API"
```

You can also specify the "-" with the "Agent" that emits the warning, and be more explicit in the warn-text :

```
Warning: 299 api.blazingFrog.com "Deprecated API: use betterapi.blazingFrog.com instead. Old API maintained until 2015-06-02"
```

Warning header is specified here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.5. Warn-code 299 is generic, "Deprecated" is not standard.

You have to tell your API clients to log the HTTP warnings and monitor it.

I've never used it until now, but when my company will be more mature in Rest API I will integrate it.

> Edit (2019-04-25): As @Harry Wood mentioned it, the Warning header is in a chapter related to caching in the documentation. However, the RFC is clear `Warnings can be used for other purposes, both cache-related and otherwise.`
>
> If you prefer an alternate method, this draft https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-dalal-deprecation-header-00 suggests a new header "Deprecation".

> Edit (2021-01-04) : As @Dima Parzhitsky mentioned it, MDN says this [header is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Warning)

Comment: The warn-date at the end of the warning-value serves no purpose here, and it’s best to omit it, or you risk confusing clients: “If a recipient . . . receives a warn-date that is different from the `Date` value in the same message, the recipient MUST exclude the warning-value . . . before . . . using the message.”

Comment: If you do include the warn-date, it must be formatted in the same way as the `Date` header: `"Thu, 02 Apr 2015 12:25:32 GMT"`.

Comment: @VasiliyFaronov : you're right, because in that case (deprecated API) this warning message will always be true in the future. So if the response (with the warning message) is sent by a cache in a proxy and that the message date is different, the warning will be ignored whereas it will still be valid. I edit the response

Comment: Isn't that "warning" header related to caching though? I mean in your documentation link it mentions caching, but also that whole RFC document seems to be caching related. But the `Warning` header does look good as free-text place to describe the deprecation. The `Deprecation` and `Sunset` headers mentioned in other answers, would seem to be an emerging standard solution for describing the deprecation in a tighter more potentially machine-readable way.

Comment: You're right @HarryWood, I did not see that. The main chapter is titled "This section defines the syntax and semantics of HTTP/1.1 header fields related to caching." However, it is the only standard today. You mentioned https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-dalal-deprecation-header-00 which should be used instead. I edit the post.

Comment: `Warning` header is not related to caches only. The first sentence in the `Warning` section is "Warnings can be used for other purposes, both cache-related and otherwise."

Comment: Note that HTTP Warnings themselves [are getting deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Warning) now

Answer (score 52):

You could use [410 (Gone)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.11).

Here's how W3C's [Status Code Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) describe it:

> ### 410 (Gone)
>
> The requested resource is no longer available at the server and no
>   forwarding address is known. This condition is expected to be
>   considered permanent. Clients with link editing capabilities SHOULD
>   delete references to the Request-URI after user approval. If the
>   server does not know, or has no facility to determine, whether or not
>   the condition is permanent, the status code 404 (Not Found) SHOULD be
>   used instead. This response is cacheable unless indicated otherwise.
>
> The 410 response is primarily intended to assist the task of web
>   maintenance by notifying the recipient that the resource is
>   intentionally unavailable and that the server owners desire that
>   remote links to that resource be removed. Such an event is common for
>   limited-time, promotional services and for resources belonging to
>   individuals no longer working at the server's site. It is not
>   necessary to mark all permanently unavailable resources as "gone" or
>   to keep the mark for any length of time -- that is left to the
>   discretion of the server owner.

Comment: The problem with 410 is that it does not match the "to-be-deprecated" requirement... It works fine when the API is gone, but not that it *will* be gone in the *future*.

Comment: If you return 410 you will break your backward compatibility

Comment: `410 Gone` it's not about deprecation, it's much about method available no more. As @BenC said, the better way is to use [Warning header](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7234#section-5.5)

Comment: This could be the next phase of the deprecated API

Answer (score 18):

I would/ have gone with [301](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) (Moved Permanently) The 300 series codes are supposed to tell the client they have an action to do.

Comment: That's probably what I'll use once the endpoint is actually removed but I want to give them a chance to be notified for some time (assuming they will be looking at the HTTP headers in the response) so that they can make the necessary changes on their end.

Comment: There isnt really a status for going to move. 302 ( The requested resource resides temporarily in another location, but it can still be found at the requested URI.) ...

Comment: I'm not looking for a status but for a "standard" header to add to the response.

Comment: There's no standard header for this kind of response. You should create a header of your own and describe it in your own api's documentation.

Comment: I think any response code >= 300 is supposed to break things. 299 will allow clients to keep their application alive until the API is disabled while they make the necessary changes.

Comment: Status code is part of your REST API. Since API is agreement between client and service, so first of all you should warn clients about future breaking changes.

Some clients may not support redirections, so after getting `301 Moved Permanently` they will assume request is failed due to unknown response code (they expects `200 Success` for example).

Other words - you risk to break compatibility with clients by changing status code of response.

As @BenC said, the better way is to use [Warning header](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7234#section-5.5) to notify clients.

Comment: That "warning" header seems to be caching related.The `Deprecation` and `Sunset` headers mentioned in other answers, would seem to be an emerging standard solution to this problem.

Answer (score 14):

Refining @dret's response. There are two relevant HTTP headers for deprecation: `Deprecation` (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-dalal-deprecation-header-00) and `Sunset`.

To inform users about the planned deprecation, the `Deprecation` HTTP header should be used. This indicates that the endpoint will be dropped *some time* in the future. It also allows you to indicate the date when this was announced, and to describe alternate resources.

To inform users about the planned sunset date of the deprecated resource, the `Sunset` header should be used in addition to the Deprecation header. This is described in section #5 https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-dalal-deprecation-header-00#section-5.

Draft #11 https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-wilde-sunset-header-11 of the `Sunset` header clarifies this aspect as well in section 1.4 https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-wilde-sunset-header-11#section-1.4.

Answer (score 7):

I'd recommend a [`207 Multi-Status`](https://httpstatuses.com/207) response, indicating that it's a successful response, but it also potentially has a second deprecated status.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know about that one, but I think in practice there's a strong danger you'll be introducing a breaking change for _some_ clients by swapping to a different response code even if it's still in the 200 range. I guess you might do a sort of gentle ratcheting up of the pressure. Start with a `Deprecation` header (which clients are likely to ignore unfortunately) then later use this 207 code, then later 301 moved, then finally 410 gone!

Answer (score 7):

There is an HTTP header field called `Sunset` which is intended to signal an upcoming deprecation of a resource. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-wilde-sunset-header is in the last stages of becoming an RFC. Ideally, your API should document that it is going to use `Sunset`, so that clients can look for it and act upon it, if they want to.