# Azure Function Return Deprecated API Header

Tags: c#, azure, httpresponse, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function that sits behind a proxy. If an update occurs to the objects that get returned we want to deprecate the Function after a period of time. I'm trying to create a response with the expected content from an HTTP Header by using what was provided [in this solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884141/convention-for-http-response-header-to-notify-clients-of-deprecated-api/29623798)

> Warning: 299 - "Deprecated API"

I try to append the Azure Function like so:

```
 [FunctionName("MyAPI")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function,
        "post", Route = null)]
        HttpRequestMessage req,
        TraceWriter log)
    {            
        object response = await someService.Get();
        if (settingsService.IsDeprecated)
        {
            var httpresponse = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response, "application/json");
            httpresponse.Content.Headers.Add("Warning", "299 - Deprecated API");
            return httpresponse;
        }
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response, "application/json");
    }
```

I get the Exception

> Exception while executing function: MyAPI -> Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.

How do I append the ["Deprecated" status warning](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.5) in my API Http Response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your line to

```
httpresponse.Headers.Add("Warning", "299 - \"Deprecated API\"");
```

The quotes seem to be important there to adhere to the format requirement.