# Setting Elastic search limit to "unlimited"

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

How can i get all the results from elastic search as the results only display limit to 10 only. ihave got a query like:

```
@data = Athlete.search :load => true do
          size 15
          query do
            boolean do
              must { string q, {:fields => ["name", "other_names", "nickname", "short_name"], :phrase_slop => 5} }
              unless conditions.blank?
                conditions.each do |condition|
                  must { eval(condition) }
                end
              end
              unless excludes.blank?
                excludes.each do |exclude|
                  must_not { eval(exclude) }
                end
              end
            end
          end
          sort do
            by '_score', "desc"
          end
        end
```

i have set the limit to 15 but i wan't to make it unlimited so that i can get all the data
I can't set the limit as my data keeps on changing and i want to get all the data.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use the `from` and `size` parameters to page through all your data.  This could be very slow depending on your data and how much is in the index.

http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html

Comment: If you *really* want everything, then "If set to 0, the size will be set to Integer.MAX_VALUE.", but pagination is definitely the correct solution. I've seen clusters fall over due to requesting too much in one query.

Comment: "'size': 0" didn't work for me and using high integer values (for instance php's max) may result in fatal error. Pagination is definitely the best choice.

Comment: Yeah, `size: 0` will literally return zero results.  It is not equivalent to asking for `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.  That convention is used [in a few other places](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_size) though, which might be where the confusion comes from.

Comment: Agreed, `size : 0` is useful when you do metrics or buckets and want to count how many things are in a bucket w/o returning the actual documents.

Answer (score 13):

Another approach is to first do a `searchType: 'count'`, then and then do a normal search with `size` set to `results.count`.

The advantage here is it avoids depending on a magic number for `UPPER_BOUND` as suggested in [this similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829468/elasticsearch-query-to-return-all-records), and avoids the extra overhead of building too large of a priority queue that Shay Banon describes [here](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Non-Paged-Query-And-Performance-td2648246.html). It also lets you keep your results sorted, unlike `scan`.

The biggest disadvantage is that it requires two requests. Depending on your circumstance, this may be acceptable.

Answer (score 10):

From the [docs](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html), "Note that `from + size` can not be more than the `index.max_result_window` index setting which defaults to 10,000". So my admittedly very ad-hoc solution is to just pass `size: 10000` or 10,000 minus *from* if I use the `from` argument.

Note that following Matt's comment below, the proper way to do this if you have a larger amount of documents is to use the [scroll api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html). I have used this successfully, but only with the python interface.

Comment: It is not the window size that cannot exceed 10000. It's the from + size cannot exceed 10000. Therefore if you had the case where from = 8000 and size = 5000 it would fail even though your window size is less than 10000 by a significant amount.

Comment: is the consequence of your comment that my answer should be edited to delete the "or 10,00 minus from ... " to be correct?

Comment: Well the question is asking how can he get all the data. So your answer doesn't really work here even if you remove your subtraction suggestion. The only answer to the question is to use scrolling if you want to post about that.

Answer (score 7):

use the scan method e.g.

```
 curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_search?search_type=scan&scroll=10m&size=50' -d '
 {
    "query" : {
       "match_all" : {}
     }
 }
```

see [here](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/scan-scroll.html)

Comment: I can't use scan method as i need to do sorting for above. Is there any other way where i can just collect all the required data

Comment: Why do you need ALL the results sorted by relevance? You'll notice that search engines like google don't return more than 1,000 results. That's because the deeper you go, the more work each page requires, esp in a distributed environment.

Comment: @DrTech Which would be the right way to approach the updating of records having the value X in the Y field? (could be more that 100k documents)

Comment: Note that scan has been deprecated in 2.1: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_21_search_changes.html#breaking_21_search_changes

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy answered 3 years ago! but thanks. noted.

Comment: All scan links are dead... ElasticSearch just wants to forget about it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [search_after](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/paginate-search-results.html) to paginate, and the [Point in Time API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/point-in-time-api.html) to avoid having your data change while you paginate. Example with elasticsearch-dsl for Python:

```
from elasticsearch_dsl.connections import connections

# Set up paginated query with search_after and a fixed point_in_time
elasticsearch = connections.create_connection(hosts=[elastic_host])
pit = elasticsearch.open_point_in_time(index=MY_INDEX, keep_alive="3m")
pit_id = pit["id"]

query_size = 500
search_after = [0]
hits: List[AttrDict[str, Any]] = []
while query_size:
    if hits:
        search_after = hits[-1].meta.sort

    search = (
        Search()
        .extra(size=query_size)
        .extra(pit={"id": pit_id, "keep_alive": "5m"})
        .extra(search_after=search_after)
        .filter(filter_)
        .sort("url.keyword")  # Note you need a unique field to sort on or it may never advance
    )
    response = search.execute()
    hits = [hit for hit in response]

    pit_id = response.pit_id
    query_size = len(hits)
    for hit in hits:
        # Do work with hits
```