# Elasticsearch query with unlimited size

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm wondering if there is a way to query elasticsearch with unlimited **size** parameter in [request body search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search-request-body.html) (where default is 10).
Using ES version 2.3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting Elastic search limit to "unlimited"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396582/setting-elastic-search-limit-to-unlimited)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Scroll API.
documentation - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html

this will allow you to get unlimited data, you specificy a size and will get it in batches. 
hope that helps :)

Comment: Could you include content of the site in your answers since the site you're referencing to maybe either changed or gone?