# Is there a way to retrieve all records in a (ElasticSearch) NEST query?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm doing this query in NEST

```
var result = elasticClient.Search<SearchItemClass>( s=>
    s.Index("indexName")
     .Type("typeName")
     .Query(q => q.ConstantScore(score => score.Filter(f => f.Term("fieldName", "term"))))
);
```

And this will return 10 Hits by default.

Is there a way I can get ALL results, WITHOUT indicating .Size(value) or .Take(value)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have rephrased my inquiry. The answers from the duplicate question did not seem to help my problem.

Comment: I know that for the bare json queries there is a size parameter that defaults to 10. You can set this to a maximum of 10,000. After that you have to use scrolls and some sort of pagination to scan through the results.

Answer (score 5):

This is a dup of [Elasticsearch query to return all records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829468/elasticsearch-query-to-return-all-records). To use scan and scroll, look at the NEST documentation [here](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/search/scroll.html).

Comment: How is this a duplicate, this question refers to NEST. Your link refers to curl?

Comment: Since the "duplicate" question is actually about JSON and curl, here is a decent Nest solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37801683/152133