# How to fetch pages of results with an ElasticSearch?

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch, pagination

I am working on getting datas from an API with ElasticSearch and have some issues with fetching all the results.

I tried to use the *from* parameter without success, it even has a strange behaviour.

For example I have one request rendering me 15 results, here are the different number of results depending on the value of the parameter from :

```
from=9 - gives me 1 result
from=10 - gives me 7 results
from=11 - gives me 2 results
from=12 - gives me 5 results
from=13 - gives me 9 results
```

Thanks for helping !

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829468/elasticsearch-query-to-return-all-records

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html:

`{
       "from" : 0, "size" : 10,
       "query" : {
           "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
       }
   }`

`from` is from where to start the result ie. offset (This is applied after all your filters etc. in query). And `size` is max number of document to be return.

You should post your query also if issue persists.