# Indexing and percolating documents with elasticsearch-dsl-py

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I'm making and investigation for a seminar in retrieval information. 
I have a `json` file with a list of articles and i need to index them and after use a percolator with highlighting.

The list of steps for do this in terminal is this:
1. Create a map with percolating.

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/my-index?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "mappings": {
        "_doc": {
            "properties": {
                "title": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "query": {
                    "type": "percolator"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

2. Index a new article:

   > ```
   > curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/my-index/_doc/1?refresh&pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
   > {           
   >     "CourseId":35,
   >       "UnitId":12390,
   >       "id":"16069",
   >       "CourseName":"ARK102U_ARKEOLOJİK ALAN YÖNETİMİ",
   >       "FieldId":8,
   >       "field":"TARİH",
   >     "query": {
   >         "span_near" : {
   >             "clauses" : [
   >                 { "span_term" : { "title" : "dünya" } },
   >                 { "span_term" : { "title" : "mirası" } },
   >                 { "span_term" : { "title" : "sözleşmesi" } }
   >             ],
   >             "slop" : 0,
   >             "in_order" : true
   >         }
   >     }
   > }
   > '
   > ```
3. Percolate a documment:

   > ```
   > curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/my-index/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
   > {
   >     "query" : {
   >         "percolate" : {
   >             "field" : "query",
   >             "document" : {
   >                 "title" : "Arkeoloji, arkeolojik yöntemlerle ortaya çıkarılmış kültürleri, dünya mirası sözleşmesi sosyoloji, coğrafya, tarih, etnoloji gibi birçok bilim dalından yararlanarak araştıran ve inceleyen bilim dalıdır. Türkçeye yanlış bir şekilde> \"kazıbilim\" olarak çevrilmiş olsa da kazı, arkeolojik araştırma yöntemlerinden sadece bir tanesidir."
   >             }
   >         }
   >     },
   >
   >     "highlight": {
   >       "fields": {
   >         "title": {}
   >       }
   >     }
   > }
   > '
   > ```

I have this code until now:

```
import json
from elasticsearch_dsl import (
DocType,
Integer,
Percolator,
Text,
)

# Read the json File
json_data = open('titles.json').read()
data = json.loads(json_data)

docs = data['response']['docs']

# Creating a elasticsearch connection
# connections.create_connection(hosts=['localhost'], port=['9200'], timeout=20)
"""
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/my-index?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "mappings": {
        "_doc": {
            "properties": {
                "title": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "query": {
                    "type": "percolator"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'

"""

class Documment(DocType):
    course_id = Integer()
    unit_id = Integer()
    # title = Text()
    id = Integer()
    course_name = Text()
    field_id = Integer()
    field = Text()


    class Meta:
        index = 'titles_index'


                properties={
                    'title': Text(),
                    'query': Percolator()
                 }

"""
    "query": {
        "span_near" : {
            "clauses" : [
                { "span_term" : { "title" : "dünya" } },
                { "span_term" : { "title" : "mirası" } },
                { "span_term" : { "title" : "sözleşmesi" } }
            ],
            "slop" : 0,
            "in_order" : true
        }
    }

"""

for doc in docs:

    terms = docs['title'].split(“ ”)
    course_id = docs['CourseId']
    unit_id = docs['UnitId']
    id = docs['id']
    course_name = docs['CourseName']
    field_id = docs['FieldId']
    field = docs['field']
```

**UPDATE:**
Thank you for the answer, i have this now:

```
import json

from elasticsearch_dsl import (
    connections,
    DocType,
    Mapping,
    Percolator,
    Text
)
from elasticsearch_dsl.query import (
    SpanNear,
    SpanTerm
)
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

# Read the json File
json_data = open('titles.json').read()
data = json.loads(json_data)

docs = data['response']['docs']


# creating a new default elasticsearch connection
connections.configure(
    default={'hosts': 'localhost:9200'},
)


class Document(DocType):
    title = Text()
    query = Percolator()

    class Meta:
        index = 'title-index'
        doc_type = '_doc'

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        return super(Document, self).save(**kwargs)


# create the mappings in elasticsearch
Document.init()

# index the query
for doc in docs:
    terms = doc['title'].split(" ")
    clauses = []
    for term in terms:
        field = SpanTerm(title=term)
        clauses.append(field)
    query = SpanNear(clauses=clauses)
    item = Document(title=doc['title'],query=query)
    item.save()
```

It is working fine, but i have two goals now:

1. I'm getting the next error after indexing a randome number of items in the dict:

> ```
> elasticsearch.exceptions.AuthorizationException: TransportError(403, 
> 'cluster_block_exception', 'blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only 
> / allow delete (api)];')
> ```

I know i can solve this problem using this command: `curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'`

**UPDATE**
Finally i solved it deleting the data folder.

But now i'm making search in the index and i don't get anything:

```
>>> text='Arkeoloji, arkeolojik yöntemlerle ortaya çıkarılmış kültürleri, dünya mirası sözleşmesi sosyoloji, coğrafya, tarih, etnoloji gibi birçok bilim dalından yararlanarak araştıran ve inceleyen bilim dalıdır. Türkçeye yanlış bir şekilde> \"kazıbilim\" olarak çevrilmiş olsa da kazı, arkeolojik araştırma yöntemlerinden sadece bir tanesidir.'
>>> s = Search().using(client).query("percolate", field='query', document={'title': text}).highlight('title')
>>> print(s.to_dict())
{'query': {'percolate': {'field': 'query', 'document': {'title': 'Arkeoloji, arkeolojik yöntemlerle ortaya çıkarılmış kültürleri, dünya mirası sözleşmesi sosyoloji, coğrafya, tarih, etnoloji gibi birçok bilim dalından yararlanarak araştıran ve inceleyen bilim dalıdır. Türkçeye yanlış bir şekilde> "kazıbilim" olarak çevrilmiş olsa da kazı, arkeolojik araştırma yöntemlerinden sadece bir tanesidir.'}}}, 'highlight': {'fields': {'title': {}}}}
>>> response = s.execute()
>>> response
<Response: {}>
```

And this is my trying with `curl`:

```
 curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/title-index/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{  
    "query" : {        
        "percolate" : {       
            "field" : "query",
            "document" : {
                "title" : "Arkeoloji, arkeolojik yöntemlerle ortaya çıkarılmış kültürleri, dünya mirası sözleşmesi sosyoloji, coğrafya, tarih, etnoloji gibi birçok bilim dalından yararlanarak araştıran ve inceleyen bilim dalıdır. Türkçeye yanlış bir şekilde> \"kazıbilim\" olarak çevrilmiş olsa da kazı, arkeolojik araştırma yöntemlerinden sadece bir tanesidir."
            }
        }
    },            
    "highlight": {
      "fields": {  
        "title": {}
      }
    }
}'
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

I'm getting variable stats but not results:

```
>>> response.to_dict()
{'took': 9, 'timed_out': False, '_shards': {'total': 5, 'successful': 5, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0}, 'hits': {'total': 0, 'max_score': None, 'hits': []}}
>>> response
{'took': 12, 'timed_out': False, '_shards': {'total': 5, 'successful': 5, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0}, 'hits': {'total': 0, 'max_score': None, 'hits': []}}
>>> response
{'took': 12, 'timed_out': False, '_shards': {'total': 5, 'successful': 5, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0}, 'hits': {'total': 0, 'max_score': None, 'hits': []}}
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first step is correct, i.e. the mapping is correct. But then, you need to first index a query, that's the whole point of percolation. So let's index your query:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/my-index/_doc/my-span-query?refresh&pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{           
    "query": {
        "span_near" : {
            "clauses" : [
                { "span_term" : { "title" : "dünya" } },
                { "span_term" : { "title" : "mirası" } },
                { "span_term" : { "title" : "sözleşmesi" } }
            ],
            "slop" : 0,
            "in_order" : true
        }
    }
}'
```

Then the idea is to find out which query would match the document you're percolating, so let's percolate a document:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/my-index/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "percolate" : {
            "field" : "query",
            "document" : {
                "title" : "Arkeoloji, arkeolojik yöntemlerle ortaya çıkarılmış kültürleri, dünya mirası sözleşmesi sosyoloji, coğrafya, tarih, etnoloji gibi birçok bilim dalından yararlanarak araştıran ve inceleyen bilim dalıdır. Türkçeye yanlış bir şekilde> \"kazıbilim\" olarak çevrilmiş olsa da kazı, arkeolojik araştırma yöntemlerinden sadece bir tanesidir."
            }
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
      "fields": {
        "title": {}
      }
    }
}'
```

And you would get this response with highlighting where you can see that `my-span-query` matches the given document:

```
{
  "took": 104,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.8630463,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my-index",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "my-span-query",
        "_score": 0.8630463,
        "_source": {
          "query": {
            "span_near": {
              "clauses": [
                {
                  "span_term": {
                    "title": "dünya"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "span_term": {
                    "title": "mirası"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "span_term": {
                    "title": "sözleşmesi"
                  }
                }
              ],
              "slop": 0,
              "in_order": true
            }
          }
        },
        "fields": {
          "_percolator_document_slot": [
            0
          ]
        },
        "highlight": {
          "title": [
            "Arkeoloji, arkeolojik yöntemlerle ortaya çıkarılmış kültürleri, <em>dünya</em> <em>mirası</em> <em>sözleşmesi</em> sosyoloji, coğrafya"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

The same thing using [`elasticsearch-py-dsl`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py):

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import DocType, Text, Percolator
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

class Document(DocType):
    title = Text()
    query = Percolator()

    class Meta:
        index = 'my-index'

    def save(self, ** kwargs):
        return super(Document, self).save(** kwargs)

# 1a. create the mappings in elasticsearch
Document.init()

# 1b. or another alternative way of saving the mapping
query_mapping = elasticsearch_dsl.Mapping('_doc')
query_mapping.field('title', 'text')
query_mapping.field('query', 'percolator')
query_mapping.save('my-index')

# 2. index the query
query = Document(query={...your span query here...})
query.save()

# 3. send the percolate query
client = Elasticsearch()
response = client.search(
    index="my-index",
    body={
      "query" : {
        "percolate" : {
            "field" : "query",
            "document" : {
                "title" : "Arkeoloji, arkeolojik yöntemlerle ortaya çıkarılmış kültürleri, dünya mirası sözleşmesi sosyoloji, coğrafya, tarih, etnoloji gibi birçok bilim dalından yararlanarak araştıran ve inceleyen bilim dalıdır. Türkçeye yanlış bir şekilde> \"kazıbilim\" olarak çevrilmiş olsa da kazı, arkeolojik araştırma yöntemlerinden sadece bir tanesidir."
            }
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
      "fields": {
        "title": {}
      }
    }
  }
)
```

**UPDATE 2**

There's is no reason to also store the `title` along with the query, you only need to store the query, so your code should look like this instead:

```
# index the query
for doc in docs:
    terms = doc['title'].split(" ")
    clauses = []
    for term in terms:
        field = SpanTerm(title=term)
        clauses.append(field)
    query = SpanNear(clauses=clauses)
    item = Document(query=query)         <-- change this line
    item.save()
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but i know how do this; i need do the same thing but using `elastic-search-dsl-py`.

Comment: Well, the second step (i.e. indexing the query) was not correct and could not have worked that way. Anyway, let me update my answer and add some python in there

Comment: I've added the comments before each step, it's pretty straightforward and does the same as each curl command above, 1) create the mapping for the percolator field, 2) index the query, 3) percolate a sample document.

Comment: How can i index all documents in my dictionary?

Comment: I got it, whit the second way i get a properly mapping for `_doc`, but with the first documment i'm getting a mapping for `doc`, why?

Comment: `doc` is the default type name used by the library, see here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/blob/762f0cd5dfed0bd0f1e338bc508f9ac0c226cffe/docs/persistence.rst#class-meta-options You can change that in the `Meta` class. It doesn't matter much as long as you're using the same type everywhere. It could be `foobar` for what it's worth.

Comment: That's right, thanks. Now i'm building the query using the library's types:
`for doc in docs:
    terms = doc['title'].split(" ")
    query = SpanNear()
    for term in terms:
        field = SpanTerm(field=term)`

Comment: DO you know how can i use this instead a dict?

Comment: Adding code to comments is not really legible, you should probably update your question instead.

Comment: Ok, i updated my answer, please add the new addtions to your answer, and if we can solve the final problem, i will accept your answer.
Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I've updated my answer with a slight modification to your code. Regarding the error you're getting, I think this is because your hard disk is almost full, can that be?

Comment: There you go, increase the disk space and/or make some room and you should be fine going forth.

Comment: Now it does not works, init the `Document` i get that problem: connection problem.

Comment: connection problem means that either your ES is down or you have networking issues

Comment: I haven't this problem before, now i can not put any element in the index.

Comment: what do you get if you run this `curl -XGET localhost:9200`?

Comment: Yeah, your disk was full and ES wouldn't start

Comment: Update your code please, it's needed add the title field to the index: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-percolate-query.html#_percolate_query_and_highlighting

Comment: The title field is already in the mapping, it is sufficient, but there is no need to add the title field to the query document you're indexing.

Comment: So, why i can't getting any result in the search?

Comment: How about using `Search(using=client, index="my-index")` instead? You're not specifying any index in your percolate query.

Comment: I did it with curl, it was the same result.

Comment: Do you mean my curl commands? I've executed them all through Kibana and that's how I got the result I showed you in the answer. I'll try the curls a bit later, maybe there's something I overlooked.

Comment: Did you repeat all curl commands from the beginning or only the one for searching/percolating? It is important to test this thoroughly and not a few steps in python and then a few steps in curl.

Comment: I'm testing the query for percolation, because the other querys it suppose i did with the previous code.

Comment: I tried with dictionary, with curl, with all, i get the complete index, but i doesn't not take all index for work, he only takes 12 registers.

Comment: I updated the question again. I can't understand why the searching doesn't talk all documents in the index.

Comment: What's the problem here?

Comment: I have to dive into this again, for me all the curl commands worked, I haven't tested the python code though.

Comment: I tryed adding the size value but it still doesn't now works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829468/elasticsearch-query-to-return-all-records

Comment: I created a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49719893/searching-along-more-than-180000-documents-index-does-not-return-any-results

Comment: I can't get any result. I a sigle document index i get the answer, but in the full text i can not get it.

Comment: ```{'took': 9, 'timed_out': False, '_shards': {'total': 5, 'successful': 5, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0}, 'hits': {'total': 0, 'max_score': None, 'hits': []}}
>>> 
```