# Optimizing percolator queries in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm working in a index of 170900 documents:
https://pasteboard.co/HfGrfiT.png

This are its settings:
https://pasteboard.co/HfGxDAi.png

I reviewed the index for ensure my query is correct:
https://pasteboard.co/HfGrBFC.png

I'm using the next query for percolate a text with this index:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/title-index/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'                                                                    ✔  1543  19:00:04 
{
    "query" : {
        "percolate" : {
            "field" : "query",
            "document" : {
                "title" : "Dışa, bireylerin bir arada bulunması, iletişime geçmesi, kendi sosyal mekânlarını oluşturmasıyla kamusal özellik kazanan kentsel açık mekânlar küreselleşme ve yeni yaşam biçimlerinin ortaya çıkmasıyla birlikte zedelenmeye ve önemini kaybetmeye başlamıştır. Özellikle 1990lı yıllardan itibaren inşa edilen kapalı konut sitelerinin çevresinde kalan bu alanlarda insan-çevre ilişkisi göz ardı edilmiş ve kentten kopuk, atıl durumda kalan sorunlu alanlar ortaya çıkmıştır. Çalışmanın amacı kapalı konut sitelerinin dışında kalan kamusal açık mekânların insan ve çevre ilişkisi açısından barındırdığı sorunlara dikkat çekmek, teorik bulguları İzmir kenti Mavişehir örnekleminde gerçekleştirilen ve sistematik gözlem çalışmasına dayanan bir alan çalışması ile test etmektir. Araştırma sonucunda kapalı konut sitelerinin bulunduğu yerlerde kamusal açık alanların sürdürülebilirliğinin tehdit altında olduğu, söz konusu problemin kapalı sitelerin yarattığı fiziksel ve sosyal ayrışmadan kaynaklandığı belirlenmiştir. Bunların sonucu olarak kamusal açık alanlarda etkileşime olanak vermeyen mekânlar ortaya çıkmakta, kullanım yoksunluğuna bağlı olarak güvensiz mekânlar oluşmaktadır. İzmir Mavişehirde gerçekleştirilen alan çalışmasında farklı dönemde inşa edilen ve farklı tasarım niteliklerine sahip iki site karşılaştırmalı olarak incelendiğinde teorik bulgular sistematik gözlem verileriyle de desteklenmiştir. Mavişehirde site sınırlarının olmadığı ve yaya erişiminin engellenmediği 1. etap konut yerleşiminin bulunduğu alanda yer alan park ve rekreasyon alanları-nın, Albayrak kapalı konut sitesinin bulunduğu alandaki kamusal açık alanlara göre gece ve gündüz çok daha etkin kullanıldığı, tasarım ve peyzaj elemanlarının daha nitelikli olduğu tespit edilmiştir. Albayrak konut sitesi yakın çevresindeki açık kamusal alanların tasarım ve peyzaj donatısının çok yetersiz olduğu, etkin biçimde kullanılmadığı, atıl, güvensiz ve suça meyil oluşturan ortamlar hazırladığı gözlenmiştir. Araştırma sonuçları kapalı konut sitelerinin insan ve çevre ilişkilerini zedelediğini, kamusal açık mekânların ve kamusal yaşamın sürdürülebilirliği açısından önemli açmazlar barındırdığını ortaya çıkarmıştır."
            }
        }
    },

    "highlight": {
      "fields": {
        "title": {}
      }
    }
}
'
```

But i'm getting no one results:

```
{
  "took" : 5,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

It is taking a few documents instead to search in all index, i don't know how can i change this.

**Update:**

Testing this problem with a new index i found two issues:

1. Percolator query with `span_near` term is full matched, it means, if i search a new query with a partial term, the search engine won't find any match in the index.

In order to get a full search support, how can i solve this problem?

Can anyone help me?

Thank you,

Comment: I think you use percolate query in the wrong way: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-percolate-query.html

Comment: why? i tested it with a index with only one document and it worked.

Comment: @LONGMAN, can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems is a language problem.

For solve this we will use a custom analyzer: we will sure lower case in all terms and we will do it in `turkish` language (in this case all documents' common language is turkish).

First, we will create a custom filter: `turkish = analysis.token_filter('turkish_lowercase', type="lowercase", language="turkish")`

Second, we will create a custom analyzer that use the new filter:

```
turkish_lowercase = analyzer('turkish_lowercase',
    type = "custom",
    tokenizer="standard",
    filter=[turkish],
)
```

Third, we will apply this analyzer to the proper field:

```
class Document(DocType):
    title = Text(
        analyzer=turkish_lowercase,
        # filter=turkish
        )
    query = Percolator(
    )    # query is a percolator

    class Meta:
        index = 'titles' # index name
        doc_type = '_doc'

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        return super(Document, self).save(**kwargs)
```

We will obtain a index like this:

```
{
   "titles":{
      "aliases":{

      },
      "mappings":{
         "_doc":{
            "properties":{
               "query":{
                  "type":"percolator"
               },
               "title":{
                  "type":"text",
                  "analyzer":"turkish_lowercase"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "settings":{
         "index":{
            "number_of_shards":"5",
            "provided_name":"titles",
            "analysis":{
               "filter":{
                  "turkish_lowercase":{
                     "type":"lowercase",
                     "language":"turkish"
                  }
               },
               "analyzer":{
                  "turkish_lowercase":{
                     "filter":[
                        "turkish_lowercase"
                     ],
                     "type":"custom",
                     "tokenizer":"standard"
                  }
               }
            },
            "number_of_replicas":"1",
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Now, we going to re-built the index.

Now we can get results using percolator:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search
from elasticsearch_dsl.query import Query

class Percolate(Query):
    name = 'percolate'

client = Elasticsearch()

index = 'titles'
text = "Bireylerin bir arada bulunması, iletişime geçmesi, kendi sosyal mekânlarını oluşturmasıyla kamusal özellik kazanan kentsel açık mekânlar küreselleşme ve yeni yaşam biçimlerinin ortaya çıkmasıyla birlikte zedelenmeye ve önemini kaybetmeye başlamıştır. Özellikle 1990’lı yıllardan itibaren inşa edilen kapalı konut sitelerinin çevresinde kalan bu alanlarda insan-çevre ilişkisi göz ardı edilmiş ve kentten kopuk, atıl durumda kalan sorunlu alanlar ortaya çıkmıştır. Çalışmanın amacı kapalı konut sitelerinin dışında kalan kamusal açık mekânların insan ve çevre ilişkisi açısından barındırdığı sorunlara dikkat çekmek, teorik bulguları İzmir kenti Mavişehir örnekleminde gerçekleştirilen ve sistematik gözlem çalışmasına dayanan bir alan çalışması ile test etmektir. Araştırma sonucunda kapalı konut sitelerinin bulunduğu yerlerde kamusal açık alanların sürdürülebilirliğinin tehdit altında olduğu, söz konusu problemin kapalı sitelerin yarattığı fiziksel ve sosyal ayrışmadan kaynaklandığı belirlenmiştir. Bunların sonucu olarak kamusal açık alanlarda etkileşime olanak vermeyen mekânlar ortaya çıkmakta, kullanım yoksunluğuna bağlı olarak güvensiz mekânlar oluşmaktadır. İzmir Mavişehir’de gerçekleştirilen alan çalışmasında farklı dönemde inşa edilen ve farklı tasarım niteliklerine sahip iki site karşılaştırmalı olarak incelendiğinde teorik bulgular sistematik gözlem verileriyle de desteklenmiştir. Mavişehir’de site sınırlarının olmadığı ve yaya erişiminin engellenmediği 1. etap konut yerleşiminin bulunduğu alanda yer alan park ve rekreasyon alanlarının, Albayrak kapalı konut sitesinin bulunduğu alandaki kamusal açık alanlara göre gece ve gündüz çok daha etkin kullanıldığı, tasarım ve peyzaj elemanlarının daha nitelikli olduğu tespit edilmiştir. Albayrak konut sitesi yakın çevresindeki açık kamusal alanların tasarım ve peyzaj donatısının çok yetersiz olduğu, etkin biçimde kullanılmadığı, atıl, güvensiz ve suça meyil oluşturan ortamlar hazırladığı gözlenmiştir. Araştırma sonuçları kapalı konut sitelerinin insan ve andçevre ilişkilerini zedelediğini, kamusal açık mekânların ve kamusal yaşamın sürdürülebilirliği açısından önemli açmazlar barındırdığını ortaya çıkarmıştır. Anahtar sözcükler: İnsan-çevre ilişkisi; kamusal açık alanlar; kapalı konut siteleri."

s = Search().using(client).index(index).query("percolate", field='query', document={'title': text}).highlight('title')

s = s.highlight_options(pre_tags='<a href=\"\">', post_tags='</a>')

print(s.to_dict())

response = s.execute()

for hit in response:
    for fragment in hit.meta.highlight.title:
        print(fragment)
```